# Elliptical galaxy classification

Tags: galaxy, astrophysics, classification

The elliptical galaxy (Hubble) classification goes from E0 to E7, with E0 being spherical and E7 being the most flattened. I understand that the angle at which the elliptical is viewed affects this number (0-7) after E.

Given that E0 and E7 are the two extremes of elliptical classification, does that mean that an elliptical is E0 if face-on and E7 if edge-on? Or vice versa? Or have I got this completely wrong and it means neither?

Answer (score 2):

An E0 galaxy appears circular. That could be because it is spherical or it could be because it is an ellipsoid seen at an inclination angle where it appears circular.

An E7 galaxy appears highly flattened. It must be an extremely ellipsoidal galaxy, since galaxies that are nearly spherical will appear roughly circular when seen from any angle.